# Access DOM element in jQuery plugin on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a personal plugin, and it needs to do an action when it hovers over a specific element. I'm running `console.log($(this));` and `console.log($this);` (I have `var $this = $(this)` before I declare my default options.

Anyways, when logging that stuff out to the console, I just get an object with the Node information, i.e. `<li id="some_id_here"></li>`, but none of the text within that `<li>` (there is text inside of it, as well as a `<span>...</span>`.

Can anybody help me here? Not sure what I need to do to grab the actual text of the `<li>`...

Thank you!

**Note:** It was indeed the case of me assigning `$this = $(this)`. Once I adjusted the nomenclature, it all fell into place. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `.innerText` and `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Those usually show up within the Object that I would have logged out. It's just a blank object, wrapped with li tags...

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with my declaration of $this = $(this)...

Comment: The text should show up. Can you post some html ?

Comment: Works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/wRgNC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **$this = $(this);** then you can simply do:

```
$this.html(); // Retrieve HTML inside "<li>" referenced by $this
$this.text(); // Retrieve plain text inside "<li>" referenced by $this
```

So you could try:

```
console.log( $this.html() );
```

For furthermore reading, take a look to jQuery **.html()** and **.text()** methods documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
console.log($(this).html())
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing `this` inside a jQuery plugin is a jQuery object, there is no need to do the `$(this)`, take a look at [signs of a poorly writter jQuery plugin](http://remysharp.com/2010/06/03/signs-of-a-poorly-written-jquery-plugin/)

If you want the html of your element do `this.html();`

If you want the text, do `this.text();`

If you just do `console.log(this)`, you normally see a little arrow on the left side, that lets you expand the element.

Comment: I think that little arrow on the side may be the key.

Comment: This is [incorrect](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).  In a jQuery event handler function, `this` is a reference to the triggering DOM element.  To get a jQuery object, you have to do a `$(this)`.

Comment: Josh, he's right, in this case it is a plugin. I'll +1 to counter the downvote.

Comment: Ah yes - the question is kind of ambiguous as to whether he's having a problem in an event handler; I was assuming the `console.log` call is happening in a handler (it may very well be).  I'd un-downvote, but [I can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem/19307#19307).

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(this);
```

If you log the plain DOM element (instead of the jQuery wrapper object), your console should allow you to inspect the the element's children.